# Adding legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyquant

I have looked through similar questions and I have a feeling I have done everything. Still not getting the desire output. I am using **ggplot2** and **tidyquant** packages to visualize data with 2 financial trends I am trying to display a legend that contains trends line coloron plot

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, price)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA, n = 50, size = 1 , col = "red" , show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA, n = 200, size = 1 , col = "blue", show.legend= TRUE)+
  theme_tq()
```

[image]

Comment: does it still not show the legend if you omit "+ theme_tq()" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(date = 1:1000, price = cumsum(rnorm(1000)))
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, price)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ma(aes(color = 'MA50'),  ma_fun = SMA, n = 50, size = 1 ,show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_ma(aes(color =  'MA200'), ma_fun = SMA, n = 200, size = 1 , show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Legend', 
                      guide = 'legend',
                      values = c('MA50' = 'red',
                                 'MA200' = 'blue'), 
                      labels = c('SMA(50)',
                                 'SMA(200)'))
```

[image]

Comment: really should one add a manual scale to draw the legend? I have never used tidyquant, but this is a bit strange behaviour, IMO.

Comment: You dont have to use a manual scale. But he wanted `red` and `blue` and not the default colors. Adding a nice title to the legend does not do any harm as well.

Comment: ok got it. I thought his problem was that he did not get any legend at all

Comment: Great, Thanks Martin. Now worries, nice title is already on the plot ;)